# How to export style into external stylesheet in styled-components?

Tags: css, stylesheet, styled-components

I am using styled-components in my project, but it just creates a style tag in the head. Is there any way to export those styles into external stylesheet?

**NOTE:** I am using Webpack.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the [`extract-text-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) in order to extract the imports into a separate external css file.

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can u share your configuration?

Comment: var cssDev = ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
 fallback: "style-loader",
 publicPath: "/_dist",
 use: [
  "css-loader",
 ]
});

Comment: OK, and did you added the plugin it self to the plugins list?

Comment: There are a number of people with this same issue and I am starting to think there is a bug somewhere. Did you manage to fix it?